# Transfer from iPad 1 to iPad 2

Tags: ipad, ios

I understand that backing up in iTunes then restoring the backup to the new device should transfer everything.

But thinking specifically about the case of upgrading my iPad 1 to an iPad 2: Are there any issues I should be aware of if backing up from an original iPad 1 and then restoring to an iPad 2?

Answer (score 1):

It'll eat all your apps souls? Aside from that you should be fine, the process works pretty well.